# How to use EventListener inside an array with row element

Tags: appcelerator-mobile

I am using Appcelerator Studio to design a slider menu. Now i need to add EventListener to those slider menu rows. Please tell me how to use EventListener on clicking 'Help' so that i can give some condition within it? My code is below:

```
var menuTitles = [{title : 'Home'
}, {
title : 'Help'
},{
title: 'Privacy Policy'
}, {
title : 'About Us'
}, {
title : 'Rate This App'
}, {
title : 'Logout'
}];
//Tableview
var tableView = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
data : menuTitles,
allowsSelection:true
});
menuWindow.add(tableView);
console.log(menuTitles[0]);
//console.log(tableView.data);
menuTitles[0].addEventListener('click', function(){   // It seems wrong.
alert("");
some more operation i need to perform inside this actually
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the event listener onto the parent element, in this case the tableView and then select the item you want that using event bubbling, the example code below selects it on the row index `e.index` but you could easily change this to `e.row.title` and do a string comparison / add any custom property to the row object and check it with `e.row`

```
tableView.addEventListener('click', function (e) { 
    if (e.index === 1) {

    } else if (e.index === 2){

    }

    etc....

});
```